# Don't want the subsection number to be italisized

Tags: sectioning

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}                                     
{\normalfont\itshape}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

This gives the subsection title as,
*1.1 Subsection*

Instead, I want,
1.1 *Subsection*

Comment: Okay.. I have editted the MWE ..

Comment: typo 'edited' in the earlier comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}                                     
{\normalfont}
{\thesubsection}{1em}{\itshape}
```

B.t.w. note you should use the NFSS syntax: `\itshape`, `\bfseries`, &c., instead of `\it`, `\bf`, &c'.

Comment: Best! That helps..